# Kinetic energy conservation in a collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Kinetic energy conservation in collision.

In any type of collision type of collision if we take the system to comprised of both bodies then the net external force is zero. So the work done by external force is also zero. By the relation $W=K_f-K_i$ as $W$ is zero hence kinetic energy is conserved. But this not the case.

Can you tell me what is the flaw in my argument? Some people say that the argument has neglected the fact that some kinetic energy is transformed into heat. But heat is created due to the interactions between bodies during collision which is thus an internal force and thus shouldn't affect kinetic energy.

Comment: What is k1 and k2 here and why are you subtracting them? You state "this is not the case" but provide no supporting evidence or facts.

Comment: BMS edited it and made it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $W_\text{net,ext}=K_f-K_i$ is only correct when the only form of energy being transformed is kinetic. If you have other forms of energy that change value, this equation won't work.

If you want to look at the system of the two colliding objects, you are correct that $W=0$ (though for a slightly different reason than what you stated; the net force is zero, but this doesn't mean the net work by external forces is zero.) A more encompassing equation than the one you're using is

$$W_\text{net,ext}=\Delta E_\text{tot}=\Delta K + \Delta E_\text{thermal} + \Delta U_\text{potential}+\cdots.$$

So, since $W=0$, the decrease in kinetic energy is accompanied by an increase in other forms of energy, such as thermal energy, acoustic, etc. (not sure what the "etc." is actually).

To more directly address your concern, internal forces absolutely can and do affect kinetic energy, even if the work done by external forces is zero. **But just knowing that $W_\text{net,ext}=0$ doesn't tell you how the internal energies transform; only that the total sum is constant.**

(Above I assumed that heat $Q$ added to the system is zero.)

Answer (score 1):

In a perfectly elastic collision the energy is conserved. In general the change in total kinetic energy is

$$\Delta K = \frac{1}{2} (\epsilon^2-1) \frac{v_{rel}^2}{\frac{1}{m_1}+\frac{1}{m_2}} $$

you can work out the equations yourself given the answer to [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/80906/392).

So when the coefficient of restitution is *one* ($\epsilon=1$) then $\Delta K=0$. When the COR is *zero* then all the relative velocity is absorbed into friction and heat and thus $\Delta K = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{v_{rel}^2}{\frac{1}{m_1}+\frac{1}{m_2}}$.