# How to calculate the force in an "impulse based reaction model"?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision

I have a sphere moving forward with `v (pre collision) = v1i`

A second sphere colliding with the first one has its own pre collision `velocity = v2i`

The collision should be not totally inelastic (like, you know, the case of two human bodies colliding each other), but for my purpose I think I can consider the coefficient of restitution = 0

Using the formula

$$ I  = mv_f - mv_0$$

and replacing `I` with `F * (delta)t`
I woul like to know how can I compute that `F`, since I don't know what will be `v(post collision)` because it is my final unknown to compute. And I think that force should be computed with the relative velocity of the two spheres, but I have no idea at the moment on how to proceed. Any suggestion will be strongly appreciated.

UPDATE

Thank you for your suggestion ja72.

So in that case can I write something like this?

$$  F *\Delta t = \frac{ (\epsilon+1) \left(v_2-v_1\right)}{\frac{1}{m_1}+\frac{1}{m_2}} $$

But in this case, how am I supposed to evaluate final velocity of the two spheres?

Comment: Is the collision eleastic, ineleastic or somewhere in the middle ? What is its coefficient of restitution ?

Comment: @rijulgupta the coefficient of restitution should be something closer to 0 rather than in the middle but to avoid complex calculations, for my purpose, I can conider it as 0. I updated my question

Comment: @ja72 Just read that question. I followed then the link to stackoverflow, which would be the interesting one. Unfortunately due to my lack of knowledge in physics and to the fact that is someone else code, I have difficulties in understanding

Comment: Did you see the answer? It shows how to calculate the momentum transfer (impulse $J$) in general.

Comment: @ja72 I updated my question

Comment: How did you come to the final equation you wrote ?

Comment: @rijulgupta thanks to ja72 suggestion which led me to [this page](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80872/newtons-cradle-collision-theory) which tells the general equation for impulse. I just wrote F * dt instead of J, asking for comfirmation

Comment: Did you read the rest of the answer there ? It has been shown how to calculate the velocities ! You find impulse, change in velocities and therefore final velocities.

Comment: woah, I misread those $$ \Delta $$ Reading fast I thought they were initial velocities and did not care too much. I'm so distract. Thank you dude, I'll wait enought points to vote all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you proceed,

Since $ = 0$, bodies stick after collision

Total momentum remains conserved therefore:

> $m_1v_{1i} + m_2v_{2i} = (m_1 +  m_2) v_f$

Solve for $v_f$ and then,

> $ I = m_1 v_f - m_1 v_1$
>   $ F = I/{dt}$

Addendum :

IF $e\neq 0$ use

> $e = \frac{ \overrightarrow{v_{2f}} - \overrightarrow{v_{1f}}}{\overrightarrow{v_{1i}} - \overrightarrow{v_{2i}}}$
>
> $e = \frac{\mbox{relative velocity after collision}}{\mbox{relative velocity before collision}}$

Use this along with momentum conservation, the difficulty would then be determined by how many variable's you can eliminate by using given values or otherwise.

As [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80872/newtons-cradle-collision-theory) question mathematically proves, Yes you can find momentum using that equation.

To find the final velocities use:

> $ \Delta v = I/m$
>   $ v_{1f} = v_{1i} + \Delta v$

Comment: ow god, I always ask myself why I don't answer myself correctly before asking in such cases, maybe because I'm am no enught sure of my basis in certain topics. That's a great starting point, thank you

Comment: Just one more question, at this point.. if  e!=0 thigs get too complicated or impossible without final velocity?

Comment: Is your query resolved now ?

Comment: I have updated my question. Can we say that your `if e=0` is a particular case of that I added to my question as an update? So can I say that this is the general rule even in the case of elastic collision? (would be perfect)

Comment: sorry, I am just going through this and updated my question with some information and a new doubt